# Is it reasonable to expect a Neural Net setup to do regression to be able to extrapolate beyond input data that is has seen

Tags: neural-network, keras

I am trying to see if given a quadratic equation of the form,

[image]

whether I can get a neural network setup to do regression to replicate it.

I have found that if my training x levels are in the range of say 0 to .5 and I test on levels out of that range, say .5 to 1.0 aka extrapolating, then the test data y estimates do not well resemble the expected y levels.  However, if the test x levels are also from within the same 0 to .5 range, aka interpolating, but not the same as any of the training x levels then the test data y estimates are very close to the expected y levels.

I'm not sure whether this is an obvious result or not.

I guess I have 2 questions.

1. Is it obvious that a neural network trying to replicate a quadratic
   function with x test levels in the same range of the training x
   levels would give good y estimates?
2. Can I get a neural network trying to replicate a quadratic function
   with x test levels out of the range of the training x levels to give
   good y estimates?

If it helps I used keras to model the network and used the following architecture :

```
model = Sequential()

model.add(Dense(30, input_dim=1, init='normal', activation='relu'))

model.add(Dense(30, init='normal', activation='relu'))

model.add(Dropout(0.5))

model.add(Dense(1, init='normal'))
```

## Compile model

```
model.compile(loss='mse', optimizer='rmsprop', metrics=['accuracy'])
```

## Fit the model

```
model.fit(Xtrain, Ytrain, nb_epoch=500, batch_size=1)
```

Comment: A neural network that could recognize and extrapolate an arbitrary non-linear function would have to be much more complex